# AWS Make two database operations in one request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my application, I'm making a database insert in one call but now I found I have to make another database operation at the same time. I'm using AWS.

Since dynamodb breaks away from a lot of the norm is the following be possible?

Is it possible, encouraged or discouraged to do two operations at once?

I need to insert a record into one table and then update another table.

- insert record into table A
- update record in table b with new values for one key

Comment: of course it's possible.  Dynamo is nearly unlimited in its scale.  If you need consistency, you just need to make sure you structure your operations to be consistent regardless of how much is going on at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what DynamoDB transactions are built for. Write in one table and update in another in an ACID compliant manner.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

If you don't require ACID properties, then you can use BatchWriteItem:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html